# How functionality of unselected version of dependency is resolved in Bill Of Material in maven?

Tags: maven, dependencies, dependency-management

For example, if dependencies for project A is defined as A -> B -> C -> D 2.0 and A -> E -> D 1.0, 
then D 1.0 will be used when building project A because the path from A to D through E is shorter.

But in this case since functionality of artifact C is dependent on version 2.0 of D which is rejected due to Bill Of Materials,
then how functionality of C will be working in project A as C depends on version 2.0 of D which is not available in project A due to Bill Of Materials.

Answer (score 0):

In that case C will not be working. It is that plain and simple.